# Make custom dynamic cells NOT reusable in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, called `MessageCell`.

I initialise the cell like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    MessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"messageCell"];

    // more code

   return cell;

}
```

In each custom cell I have a checkbox used to mark this cell. When a cell is marked it is being added to an array, and vice versa.

While this works in terms of data, the UI is not reflecting it as it should. What happens is that in addition to the marked cell, other cells are being marked.

I assume this behaviour stems from cell reusability, i.e when I mark a cell as selected it has a common pointer with all future cells in this screen position.

For this reason, I want to use "normal" non-reusable cells.

So I tried:

```
  MessageCell *cell = [[MessageCell alloc] init];
```

OR:

```
  MessageCell *cell = [[MessageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
```

But both of them resulted in displaying empty cells.

Comment: does initwithstyle not work when you use the reuse identifier?  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyIdentifierFromStoryboard"];i gues it will make a new cell , just use the layout then

Comment: Implement `prepareForReuse` for your custom `UITableViewCell` and clean as necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Desdenova, sounds promising. do you mind elaborating in an answer?

Comment: @Matanya Sure but I don't know how you mark the cell. Just unmark it there. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will mark it again for the required cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still want to reuse cells! Just check your data and set the checkbox to checked or unchecked in your cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
MessageCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"messageCell"];

if (condition cell should be checked) //set the cells checkbox to checked
else //set the cells checkbox to unchecked
```

Or some approach like that.

PS on re-reading your question:
do you really need a reference to a cell in your array? Can't you for example store the indexPath and use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if you need to make a cell out of it?

Comment: this code is only called when the table is generated. The select code is an IBAction which is called whenever the checkbox is marked: `sender.selected = !sender.isSelected`

Comment: Then just call `[self.tableView reloadData];` when your data changes (in your IBAction method)!

Comment: This is the most counter-intuitive thing Apple has ever done, as far as I can tell, for developers. You change one cell, it's reused and other cells get that change. Unless you specify it here as well. Amazingly hard to identify for me - you really have to understand UITableViewCells and how they work.

Comment: When using this (the same way I thought to do it), my cells appear as if reused, and then switch to the correct value. For example, I will scroll up and a cell will appear with the checkbox checked and only then uncheck itself... This happen to anyone else?